# Is there an intuitive way of viewing the Law of Total Expectation $\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]\big]=\mathbb{E}[X]?$

Tags: probability, intuition, expectation, conditional-expectation

> **Law of total expectation**
>
> If $\mathbb{E}\big[|X|\big]$ finite then for any $Y,\;\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]\big]=\mathbb{E}[X]$

I remember reading this for the first time and thinking... *hold up, what?*

The proof is simple, but I am wondering whether there is an intuitive reason why we might expect this result?

Comment: Averaging averages of separate sub-groups weighted by size of those sub-groups will yield the average of the large group.

Answer (score 6):

The conditional expectation of $X$ with respect to $Y$ is our best estimate of $X$ given exact knowledge of $Y.$ The expectation of any variable is our best estimate, given no specific knowledge about any variable at all. It seems reasonable then that our a priori expectation of the variable $E[X|Y]$ *before* we have any knowledge of $Y$ is just the general expectation of $X.$

Answer (score 6):

That depends on why this is violating your intuition.  For me, the basic intuition behind it is, $E(X)$ is the expected value of the random variable $X$, across all possible conditions.  For any random variable $Y$, let $y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots$ represent the possible values of $Y$.  Then these $y_i$ are also, in some sense, a "cover set" of all possible conditions, and therefore if you do a weighted average of the conditional expected values $E(X \mid Y)$, you should obtain the overall expected value of $X, E(X)$.